# How to replace a string with another string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

INPUT TEXT FROM FILE :

```
someother block {
  enable route yes;
  dhcp auto;
  ....
}
options { 
  dnssec-enable yes;
  dnssec-validation yes;
  dnssec-lookaside auto;
 .....
}
```

I would like to replace all the "yes" and "auto" text in ***options*** block ***ONLY*** with "no" and "manual" respectively.

How can I accomplish this?

Here is my execution but the text is not replaced.

```
String dataPattern  = "\noptions \\{\\s*\n(dnssec-[a-z]+ ([a-z]+));";
Pattern filePattern = Pattern.compile(dataPattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher filePatternMatcher = filePattern.matcher(input);
if(filePatternMatcher.find()){
        System.out.println("0 - "+filePatternMatcher.group(0)); //0 - \ndnssec-enable yes;
        System.out.println("1 - "+filePatternMatcher.group(1)); //1 - dnssec-enable yes

        System.out.println("2 - "+filePatternMatcher.group(2)); //2 - yes
        String value = filePatternMatcher.group(2);
        value.replaceAll("\ndnssec-enable ([a-z]+);", "$1somethingelse");
        System.out.println("new replaced text:"+value); \\ new-replaced text: yes
}
```

Comment: Do you need regex for that? You could just string-replace `yes;` with `no;` and `auto;` with `manual;`.

Comment: I dont think its that simple. Since there can be multiple lines containing "yes" and "auto". The text provided at the top is read from a file.

Comment: I need to replace the `yes` and `auto` only if its within the matching `options {` block.

Comment: See [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-). *FYI:* The reason your code is not working, is because [`String.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) *returns* the updated value. It does not modify the input string. Read the javadoc!!

Comment: @DennySutedja JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: try value.replace("Yes","No").replace("Auto","Manual")

Comment: Are the property names unique across all blocks? Then you could simply replace `dnssec-enable yes` with `dnssec-enable no` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could complete it with just Replace function!

```
    String test="someother block {" +
            "  enable route yes;" +
            "  dhcp auto;" +
            "  ...." +
            "}" +
            "options { " +
            "  dnssec-enable yes;" +
            "  dnssec-validation yes;" +
            "  dnssec-lookaside auto;" +
            " ....." +
            "}";

    String result;

    int opStartIndex=test.indexOf("options");
    int opEndIndex=opStartIndex+ test.substring(opStartIndex).indexOf("}");
    result=test.substring(0,opStartIndex)+test.substring(opStartIndex, opEndIndex).replace("yes","no").replace("auto","manual")+test.substring(opEndIndex);
    System.out.println(result);
```